# Configurable Swatches - showing up in product images

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, swatches, color-swatches

I am having some issues with configurable products swatches and the swatch images showing up in the product images. Scenarios below. Thanks!

Scenario 1: (everything works correctly!) Product A - Red - QTY:5 Product A - Blue - QTY: 3

Scenario 2: Product A - Red - QTY: 0 (out of stock) Product A - Blue - QTY 3

In scenario two the swatch image disappears from the swatches for red ... which is fine. BUT now the swatch appears as a product image in the product images for the configurable product. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Do you maybe use a custom design or a third party extensions that does something with the media gallery? The swatches functionality has been introduced in 1.9, which is relatively recent. It could be you're still using an outdated extension that doesn't take swatches into account.

I've just replicated your product set up (in 1.9.2.2) and this seems to work as expected;

[image]

[image]

What does your Configurable product Images tab configuration look like? It should look like this;

[image]

Could you maybe place a screenshot or a URL?

Answer (score 0):

I think it will just be sufficient to suffix swatch image names with **-swatch** :

*Red-swatch*

*Blue-swatch*